# C++/CLI project is always fully rebuilt when a referenced c# dll is updated

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI project with multiple source files in it now. I have a separate c# project which i added as a reference in the C++/CLI project and used a method from the c# code in one of the .cpp files.

When i update the c# code, what i have found is that the c++/CLI project is fully rebuilt, even source files which don't reference the c# code. MSBuild logs messages similar to the below in the output

> Interface.cpp will be compiled because $somepath\Helper.dll was
>   modified at $time.

I initially expected it to rebuild/build only the specific c++ file i referenced the project in. Is there anyway to work around this ?

Edit :

I wrote the specific c# method onto a separate c++/cli project and tried referencing that in my original c++/cli project. With this approach, my original project gets rebuilt only when something in the header file changes like adding a new method.

> Interface.cpp will be compiled because $somepath\Helper.dll.metagen was
>   modified at $time.

If I change the body of an existing method in the cpp file, the rebuild doesn't happen. Would love to achieve that same behavior when referencing the c# dll.

Comment: That metagen file says that you already have the "Enable managed incremental build" option set to Yes.  That's where the buck stops.  It tends to be a good kind of problem to have, indicating that you are compiling far too much native C++ code with /clr in effect.  Isolating such code in its own DLL or static library so it gets the full optimizer love is always a good idea.

Comment: Got it. Its just that even an accidental save or a very minor change like a typo fix on the c# project kicks off the cpp project rebuild which is fairly big and takes a while to compile/link. If there is no way around it, then I will probably have to look at a different way of achieving what I want.